# a question on sum of q_binomials

Tags: summation, hypergeometric-function, q-series

I was trying to calculate something and at some point I get the following sum:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{t=0,t \text{ even}}^{s}{s+3n \brack s-t}\sum_{i = 0}^{t/2}q^{2i^2}{t/2+2n-i \brack t/2-i}{n \brack 2i}x^t
\end{equation}
 can it be simplified by using a $q$-binomial identity?